# Castle Windsor Transient Lifestyle Not Activating

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm having a problem with a component in my container with a Transient lifestyle. The first time I call resolve, I hit the constructor of the implementation type as expected.

However, the second time I call resolve, a new instance is not constructed. Rather, the existing instance is reused. I don't think this should happen, since my component's LifestyleType is set to Transient (I have verified this at runtime in debugging mode at a breakpoint):

```
Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object))[33].ComponentModel.LifestyleType 
// 33 is the verified index of my component type...this returns Transient as expected
```

At the same breakpoint, I have run the following in the immediate window and verified that a new instance is not constructed:

```
  Resolve(Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object))[33].Service)
  // this does NOT return a new instance!
  // ...It returns the same instance from the first time Resolve was called. 
  // I can tell by the state of the object and because the constructor on the object is not called.
```

Update:

I've narrowed the problem down, I think.

The below test fails:

```
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Kernel.AddComponent<MyLazyComponentLoader>(typeof (ILazyComponentLoader));

    var instance1 = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
    var instance2 = container.Resolve<MyClass>();

    Assert.AreNotSame(instance1, instance2);
```

MyLazyComponentLoader simply returns 
Component.For(service)

which is defaulting to Singleton LifestyleType (even though it shows up as Unknown on the ComponentModel. Is this by design?

Thanks.

Comment: That does not feel right. Can you reproduce it in a test?

Comment: Yes, the default lifestyle is singleton, Unknown means it's not specified explicitly, but Windsor treats it as if you specified Singleton. If you want it to be transient, be explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Krzysztof Koźmic: Yes, the default lifestyle is singleton, Unknown means it's not specified explicitly, but Windsor treats it as if you specified Singleton. If you want it to be transient, be explicit.